# How to get an application listening ports with windows c++ api

Tags: winapi, network-monitoring, windows-networking

As show in Windows Resource Monitor:

[image]

I want to analyse network traffic of an application, but I dont know the Windows API. I used [scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) or [wireshark](http://wireshark.org), but I don't know what data packages are this application.

So, I want to get the listening port first. But I don't know the API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GetTcpTable2()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcptable2) or [`GetExtendedTcpTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getextendedtcptable) to enumerate open TCP ports,  determining which ports are listeners, and get each one's owning process.

You can use [`GetExtendedUdpTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getextendedudptable) to enumerate open UDP ports and get each one's owning process.